# Query does not do what I want it to do

Tags: php, mysql

```
$mpn = $P[0];
$qty = $P[14];
$mysql_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'my_db', 'my_pass');
if (!$mysql_connection) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('my_db', $mysql_connection);
$id = mysql_query("SELECT productid FROM my_table_2 WHERE value = '$mpn'");
if (!$id) { 
    return("XXX-99999");
}
mysql_select_db('my_db', $mysql_connection);
$sku = mysql_query("SELECT productcode FROM my_table WHERE productid = $id");
if (!$sku) { 
    return("XXX-99999");
}
mysql_select_db('my_db', $mysql_connection);
$qty2 = mysql_query("SELECT avail FROM my_table WHERE productcode = '$sku'");
if (!$qty2) { 
    return("XXX-99999");
}
if ($qty2 <1 && $qty >0 && $qty2 != $qty) { 
    return($sku);
}
else {
    return("XXX-99999");
}
```

I'm trying to match Manufacturers part numbers from Product feed and database to accomplish putting out of stock products from main source to secondary source. It does not work. What I am doing wrong?

This has been edited to try and explain the situation more clearly. First this is going into an app and is a snippit to be used by that app. Hence mysql instead of mysqli. The variable $mpn in the first query comes from $mpn = ($P[0]); at the top. It is in a feed and not in the database as a column. $sku in the second query comes from the result of the first query and is not in the database as a column. The app loops this code for each line of the feed.

The above fails to achieve the desired effect of providing the last argument even though I know it for sure should (I set it up). Given the new explaination can somebody help?

```
$mpn = ($P[0]);
$qty = ($P[14]);

$mysql_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass' );
if (!$mysql_connection) {
die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('db', $mysql_connection);

$tmp1 = mysql_query("SELECT productcode FROM table1 WHERE mpn != '' && mpn = '$mpn'")or die(mysql_error());
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($tmp1, MYSQL_BOTH);
$sku = $row1[0];

$tmp2 = mysql_query("SELECT avail FROM table1 WHERE productcode = '$sku'")or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($tmp2, MYSQL_NUM);
$qty2 = $row2[0];

if ($qty2 <=0 && $qty >0) { 
return($sku);
}
else {
return("XXX-99999");
}
```

Comment: "Doctor it hurts, help me!" Can you provide a little more detail than that?

Comment: I wonder what result datatype do `mysql_query()` gives.

Comment: Trying to set variables using mysql_queries

Comment: Just for future reference, you shouldn't be using php's `mysql_` functions.  Instead, try `PDO` or `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: $mpn & $qty are taken directly from a feed that is covered by the application. What I am concerned about is how to retrieve from DB $id, $sku and $qty2

Comment: Be advised this is PHP code within an application which allows it.

Comment: @Jeff's advice is good -- the `mysql_xxx()` functions have been considered obsolete for a long time. The PHP manual **strongly** recommends switching to either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` funcs or the PDO library, either of which makes it much easier to write secure code. mysqli is very easy to convert to from the old funcs, so there's no real excuse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch the data after `mysql_query`(look into mysqli instead) using `mysql_fetch_array`. After fetching assign `$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($id);` and then you can call the row and column name `$row1['productid'];`. You also do not need to open assign the database before every call. You can only do it once before running the queries and then run `mysql_close($mysql_connection)`

```
$mpn = $P[0];
$qty = $P[14];
$mysql_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'my_db', 'my_pass');
if (!$mysql_connection) {
die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('my_db', $mysql_connection);    

$id = mysql_query("SELECT productid FROM my_table_2 WHERE value = '$mpn'");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($id);
if (!$id) { return("XXX-99999");
}

$sku = mysql_query("SELECT productcode FROM my_table WHERE productid = $row1['productid']");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sku);
if (!$sku) { return("XXX-99999");
}

$qty2 = mysql_query("SELECT avail FROM my_table WHERE productcode = '$row2['productcode']'");
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($qty2);
if (!$qty2) { return("XXX-99999");
}
if ($row3['avail'] <1 && $qty >0 && $row3['avail'] != $qty) { return($row['productcode']);
}
else {return("XXX-99999");
}
mysql_close($mysql_connection);
```

This should give you more or less an idea. Use as reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Failed to aquire desired result. Be advised the Where is designed to bring about a singular result not an array.

Comment: Yes, WHERE is designed for that but you still need to fecth the data and it will add it as a single row to the array. you still need to call it from the array `$row["productid"]`

Comment: I agree it must be called as such but the code above fails, with error.

Comment: Maybe it should be called as: if ($row3 <1 && $qty >0 && $row3 != $qty) { return($row2);

Comment: ahhh perhaps... if ($row3['avail'] <1 && $qty >0 && $row3['avail'] != $qty) { return($row['productcode']); should of been if ($row3['avail'] <1 && $qty >0 && $row3['avail'] != $qty) { return($row2['productcode']);

Comment: "ahhh perhaps... if ($row3['avail'] <1 && $qty >0 && $row3['avail'] != $qty) { return($row['productcode']); should of been if ($row3['avail'] <1 && $qty >0 && $row3['avail'] != $qty) { return($row2['productcode']);" Nope that was not it either.

Comment: Please refer to this reference to see what I explained in my answer - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: I edited my original post, I'm further along. I think the problem is the usage of PHP variables inside of the mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$sku = mysql_query("SELECT productcode FROM my_table WHERE productid = $id");
```

I think it should look like:

```
$sku = mysql_query("SELECT productcode FROM my_table WHERE productid = '$id' ");
```

Comment: Also be advised that $id is always a numerical result where as $mpn and $sku can be mixed between numerical and text.